# open, fetch, into multiple variables

Tags: plsql

I am trying to get 2 variables out of a cursor without using a loop.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NAK.SET_ORDERS(P_ORDER_ID NAK.ORDER_ID%TYPE)

CURSOR C_GET_ORDER_NO IS
  SELECT O.ORDER_ID, O.ORDER_MAL FROM NAK.ORDERS O WHERE O.ORDER_ID = P_ORDER_ID;

BEGIN

  V_ORDER_SEQ := NULL;
  V_ORDER_MAL := NULL;

  OPEN C_GET_ORDER_NO;
  FETCH C_GET_ORDER_NO VALUES(O.ORDER_ID, O.ORDER_MAL)
    INTO (V_ORDER_ID, V_ORDER_MAL);
  CLOSE C_GET_ORDER_NO;

END;
```

Comment: To be more specific : do you know how i can get 2 variables? original code what i found on the internet was only with 1 variable(v_order_id) i tryed to add 1 more variable(v_order_mal)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really need an explicit cursor? You can simply do this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NAK.SET_ORDERS(P_ORDER_ID IN NAK.ORDER_ID%TYPE)

      V_ORDER_SEQ := NULL;
      V_ORDER_MAL := NULL;

    BEGIN

      SELECT O.ORDER_ID, 
             O.ORDER_MAL 
        INTO V_ORDER_SEQ,
             V_ORDER_MAL  
        FROM NAK.ORDERS O 
       WHERE O.ORDER_ID = P_ORDER_ID;

   EXCEPTION
       WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            dbms_output.put_line("No record found");
       WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line("More than one record found");
       WHEN OTHER THEN
            dbms_output.put_line("Other problem happend");
    END;
```

**Important**: this procedure will return a exception if the query doesn't return exactly one record. (ORA-01403: no data found or ORA-00913: too many values)

Alternatively you should be able to make something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NAK.SET_ORDERS(P_ORDER_ID NAK.ORDER_ID%TYPE)

CURSOR C_GET_ORDER_NO IS
  SELECT O.ORDER_ID, 
         O.ORDER_MAL 
    FROM NAK.ORDERS O 
   WHERE O.ORDER_ID = P_ORDER_ID;

BEGIN
  V_ORDER_SEQ := NULL;
  V_ORDER_MAL := NULL;

  OPEN C_GET_ORDER_NO;
  FETCH C_GET_ORDER_NO INTO V_ORDER_ID, V_ORDER_MAL;
  CLOSE C_GET_ORDER_NO;

END;
```

Comment: Yes thanks this works fine, however i would really want to use the cursor. i will be adding a lot more to this code and i want to have it in pieces by using cursors. and could u add a way to catch the exception if the query returns more than one record or none at all.

Comment: Added exceptions and the way with cursors...  By the way. If you do not have data you will have problems anyway. If you have more than one record LIMIT 1 is your friend.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer that i wanted.